# Assign values from one column to another based on levels of other factor: R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, dplyr, levels

I want to:

1. group by a factor (Site, Pos);
2. if factor 'Pos' == "A", assign chosen value ("a") to the same rows in new column ('Treat1');
3. if factor 'Pos' == "B", assign chosen value ("b") to the same rows in new column ('Treat1');
4. if factor 'Pos' == "AT", assign one value ("a") to every first row of new column ('Treat 1') where 'Pos' == A, and second value ("b") to every second row of the same.

So far I only know how to code the first 3 points, but this loop is still not performing as I would expect. It only fills the last row in the new column Treat1. 
Any ideas?

Very open to different methods of approaching this, but please bear in mind that I am an R beginner.

Repro:

```
yow <- c(1:6) 
Pos <- c("A", "B", "A", "AT", "AT", "B")
df <- as.data.frame(Pos, yow)
df$Site <-  c("low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "high")

df$Treat1 <- NA

for (i in nrow(df %>% group_by(Site)){  
  if(df$Pos[i] == "A"){
    df$Treat1[i] <- "a"
  }
  else {
    if(df$Pos[i] == "B"){
      df$Treat1[i] <- "b"
    }
  }
}
```

I expect/am looking for:

- Site Pos Treat1
- low  A   a
- low  B   b
- high A   a
- high AT  a
- high AT  b
- high B   b

This answer is cool, and does the first 3 steps my ifelse loop is failing at, but it doesn't speak to the 4th problem! 
[R Create new column of values based on the factor levels of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60500541/r-create-new-column-of-values-based-on-the-factor-levels-of-another-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `case_when` in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Pos) %>%
  mutate(Treat1 = case_when(Pos %in% c('A', 'B') ~ tolower(Pos), 
                             Pos == 'AT' ~ c('a', 'b')))


#  Pos     yow Site  Treat1
#  <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> 
#1 A         1 low   a     
#2 B         2 low   b     
#3 A         3 high  a     
#4 AT        4 high  a     
#5 AT        5 high  b     
#6 B         6 high  b
```

Comment: Hey that's a nifty answer! Thank you!

Comment: By a miracle (I've been messing around with this problem on and off for longer than I'd care to admit), I got another solution this afternoon – FINALLY! Not as neat as yours @Ronak :   
`df$Treat1 <- NA   
  df <- df %>% mutate(Treat1 = case_when(
    Pos %in% c("A") ~ "a", 
    Pos %in% c("B") ~ "b",
  ))`

Comment: Then:  `df[df$Pos == "AT", ] <-
  df[df$Pos == "AT", ] %>%  
    group_by(Site, Pos) %>%  
      mutate(Treat1 = ifelse((row_number() %% 2) == 1, "a", "b"))`

Comment: You can add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution. Not as neat as yours Ronak:

```
df$Treat1 <- NA
df <- df %>% mutate(Treat1 = case_when(
  Pos %in% c("A") ~ "a", 
  Pos %in% c("B") ~ "b",
  ))
```

Then:

```
df[df$Pos == "AT", ] <- df[df$Pos == "AT", ] %>% group_by(Site,Pos)%>% 
mutate(Treat1 = ifelse((row_number() %% 2) == 1, "a", "b"))
```